# como usar un api con javascript y la función fetch

Tags: javascript, html, api, fetch

buenas, mi duda es la siguiente tengo el codigo:

```
 const url = 'http://localhost:8080/users/[count]';
 fetch(url)
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then(function(data) {

document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = `${data.name} ${data.username}`;


})
.catch(function(error) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

que en teoria deberia agarrar la informacion el direccion http://localhost:8080/users/[count] y darme los valores name y username que se encuentrar en esta direccion.

la direccion posee lo siguiente:

```
[{"name":"Marisa Koss","username":"Adolfo.Klein","email":"Arnold29@hotmail.com","address":{"street":"Nils Mills","suite":"Apt. 415","city":"South Cortney","zipcode":"96235-6649","geo":{"lat":"-6.3807","lng":"-19.6170"}},"phone":"1-212-309-5985 x3453","website":"dovie.com","company":{"name":"Muller, Monahan and Stracke","catchPhrase":"Managed real-time matrices","bs":"rich maximize portals"}},{"name":"Ole Kulas","username":"Lesly.Walter","email":"Etha70@gmail.com","address":{"street":"White Isle","suite":"Suite 966","city":"Hermannland","zipcode":"13688","geo":{"lat":"-85.1722","lng":"133.7227"}},"phone":"1-161-247-6455 x898","website":"gina.name","company":{"name":"Rodriguez - Botsford","catchPhrase":"Extended leading edge ability","bs":"wireless evolve web-readiness"}},{"name":"Baylee Boehm","username":"Maximillia37","email":"Merl.Rath24@yahoo.com","address":{"street":"Laisha Turnpike","suite":"Suite 277","city":"Cesartown","zipcode":"43786-5148","geo":{"lat":"3.6440","lng":"153.8556"}},"phone":"(027) 633-4660 x01161","website":"amari.org","company":{"name":"Wiegand and Sons","catchPhrase":"Advanced high-level open architecture","bs":"viral productize methodologies"}},{"name":"Chanelle Kub Jr.","username":"Mac.Stoltenberg10","email":"Willis_Gutkowski10@yahoo.com","address":{"street":"Cecilia Harbor","suite":"Suite 605","city":"East Deonte","zipcode":"11840-8930","geo":{"lat":"-18.2002","lng":"105.6944"}},"phone":"071-752-1969 x96946","website":"tristin.info","company":{"name":"Corwin - Champlin","catchPhrase":"Balanced bi-directional collaboration","bs":"sticky embrace interfaces"}},{"name":"Vickie Wisozk","username":"Ladarius.Conroy98","email":"Lowell_Beer@yahoo.com","address":{"street":"Cheyenne Village","suite":"Suite 849","city":"Farrellstad","zipcode":"67187","geo":{"lat":"4.3229","lng":"-125.2004"}},"phone":"1-247-291-1942 x5040","website":"doris.com","company":{"name":"Larson, Cormier and Stoltenberg","catchPhrase":"Profound discrete leverage","bs":"integrated benchmark ROI"}},{"name":"Laury Nader","username":"Eulalia62","email":"Lempi_Schimmel91@gmail.com","address":{"street":"Parker Junction","suite":"Apt. 389","city":"New Gabe","zipcode":"00367","geo":{"lat":"37.2142","lng":"79.3023"}},"phone":"(822) 093-1471 x9308","website":"junior.biz","company":{"name":"Hodkiewicz, Sporer and McClure","catchPhrase":"Inverse zero tolerance product","bs":"distributed generate solutions"}},{"name":"Laron Walker","username":"Rosalinda38","email":"Idella.Quigley72@yahoo.com","address":{"street":"Rodriguez Knoll","suite":"Suite 488","city":"New Zakaryhaven","zipcode":"24722","geo":{"lat":"-0.9863","lng":"63.8521"}},"phone":"229-380-2044 x086","website":"jaden.biz","company":{"name":"Klein Group","catchPhrase":"Balanced foreground moderator","bs":"user-centric redefine e-markets"}},{"name":"Antonia Wilkinson","username":"Verdie.Casper","email":"Candelario.Mann@yahoo.com","address":{"street":"Kuphal Harbor","suite":"Suite 661","city":"East Gregfurt","zipcode":"91590-9271","geo":{"lat":"-87.7308","lng":"25.9781"}},"phone":"307-166-2617","website":"marques.org","company":{"name":"Treutel LLC","catchPhrase":"Public-key discrete project","bs":"24/365 transform infomediaries"}},{"name":"Mr. Mateo Gottlieb","username":"Marina0","email":"Loyal.Weissnat49@gmail.com","address":{"street":"Connelly Throughway","suite":"Apt. 439","city":"Deionfort","zipcode":"49258","geo":{"lat":"-39.2334","lng":"177.2928"}},"phone":"763-148-7666 x4871","website":"roel.net","company":{"name":"Torp - Senger","catchPhrase":"Optional responsive complexity","bs":"viral strategize portals"}},{"name":"Hermann Wolff","username":"Mckayla.Anderson","email":"Guiseppe_Heidenreich@yahoo.com","address":{"street":"Justen Courts","suite":"Suite 217","city":"Lake Jovanburgh","zipcode":"52134-2599","geo":{"lat":"17.1201","lng":"106.4603"}},"phone":"650-449-3725 x0901","website":"heloise.net","company":{"name":"Marvin and Sons","catchPhrase":"Distributed didactic forecast","bs":"bleeding-edge reintermediate action-items"}}]
```

me podrían decir cual es mi error, o que deberia hacer para conseguir los datos que necesito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El JSON que muestras debajo es un Array, por lo que deberias usar `for` o algun otro iterador para extraer los objetos antes de mostrarlos. Algo asi:

```
for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
   document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = `<p>${data[i].name} ${data[i].username}</p>`
};
```

Comment: aun asi no me esta mostrando los datos en la tabla, lo que no se es si estoy accediendo a la dirección http://localhost:8080/users/[count] bien

Comment: Puedes fijarte en las conexiones del navegador (si usas chrome en la pestaña Network en DevTools: Ctrl+Mayus+I). Ahi te podes fijar si hace la petición correctamente, si hay respuesta y que responde.

Comment: déjame revisar eso, pero puedo confirma que si hace una solicitud, ya que en la consola donde corro el api me sale lo siguiente info server: GET /users/[count]

Comment: ya revise y me sale el siguiente error Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8080/users/[count]. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. como podria solucionarlo ?

Comment: Que backend usas?

Comment: pregunta mal enfocada por motivo de CORS (necesitas habilitarlo primero para jugar con las peticiones de una API que estará abierta) https://enable-cors.org/ luego que hayas corregido el CORS, actualiza tu pregunta :D saludos y bienvenido/a al sitio! por cierto, dale una lectura a http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour esperamos verte seguido colaborando con la hermandad de StackOverflow en Español :D

Comment: estoy usando javascrip con la libreria react js y html

Comment: En el servidor, que software usas? como dijo guzgarcia debes activar CORS

Answer (score 0):

> me sale el siguiente error Fetch API cannot load localhost:8080/users/[count]. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Este error se debe cuando el cliente que solicita un recurso **se encuentra en un dominio diferente**. Es una política de seguridad que es implementada por defecto. Para solucionar éste incoveniente, en el backend se debe activar [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS); ésto por supuesto, depende del lenguaje que utilizas en el servidor.

> Puedes ver como activar CORS en el lenguaje que utilices en [éste enlace](https://enable-cors.org/)

Además, lo que envías desde el backend es un array y debes tratarlo como tal en el cliente. Puedes usar un for normal, o mejor, [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach).

```
fetch(url)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then(({ data }) => {
    data.forEach((entry) => {
      // entry.name, entry.username, etc.
    });
  });
```